# R: Merging Parts of a Graph Together

Tags: r, graph, tree

I am working with the R programming language.

I have the following "Tree" that depicts the results of a coin flipping game (start at 5 points, and 0.5 prob of +1 and 0.5 prob of -1 at each turn):

```
outcomes <- c(-1, 1)  

combinations <- expand.grid(rep(list(outcomes), 10))
colnames(combinations) <- paste("Turn", 1:10)

library(data.tree)

generate_tree <- function(node, depth, total) {
    if (depth == 0) {
        node$Set(total = total)
        return(node)
    } else {
        for (outcome in outcomes) {
            child <- node$AddChild(name = as.character(total + outcome), total = total + outcome)
            generate_tree(child, depth - 1, total + outcome)
        }
        return(node)
    }
}

root <- Node$new("Start", total = 5)

root <- generate_tree(root, 4, 5)

print(root, "total")

plot(root, "total")
```

[image]

**My Question:** Is it possible to reformat (i.e. merge) this graph such that at each turn, all "nodes" with the same "value" are collapsed into a single node? This would mean that at each turn, a given "value" could only appear once.

After reading the following references ([How to collapse branches in a phylogenetic tree by the label in their nodes or leaves?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34403957/how-to-collapse-branches-in-a-phylogenetic-tree-by-the-label-in-their-nodes-or-l), [Plotting a tree - collapsing a vector of nodes](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67724867/plotting-a-tree-collapsing-a-vector-of-nodes)) tried to do this with the following code:

```
collapse_nodes <- function(node) {
    if (node$isRoot) {
        return(node)
    } else {
        parent <- node$parent
        siblings <- parent$children
        same_value_siblings <- siblings[sapply(siblings, function(x) x$total == node$total)]
        if (length(same_value_siblings) > 1) {
            node$parent <- NULL
            parent$RemoveChild(node$name)
        }
        return(node)
    }
}
root <- Traverse(root, collapse_nodes, mode = "post-order")

print(root, "total")
plot(root, "total")
```

Unfortunately, I got the following error:

```
Error in Traverse(root, collapse_nodes, mode = "post-order") : 
  unused argument (mode = "post-order")
```

Can someone please suggest how to resolve this problem?
Thanks!

**Note:**
In the end, all nodes of the same color will merged into a single node - this is what I am trying to achieve:

[image]

Comment: You can't do what you're asking in `data.tree`. The [definition](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tree_(data_structure)#:~:text=Each%20node%20in%20the%20tree,node%20in%20the%20tree%20hierarchy) of a tree data structure is that a node can have many children but exactly one parent (or zero in the special case of the root). It is reasonable to identify and merge duplicate nodes and for each to retain their original ancestor, but you don't have a tree anymore - you need a directed graph, e.g. as ThomasIsCoding has implemented.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I guess you can use `igraph` like below

```
library(igraph)

outcomes <- c(-1, 1)
start <- 5
depth <- 7

lvls <- paste0("L", seq(depth + 1), "_")
ps <- apply(
  expand.grid(rep(list(outcomes), depth)),
  1,
  \(x) path(paste0(lvls, c(start, start + cumsum(x)))),
  simplify = FALSE
)

vs <- unique(unlist(ps))
g <- make_empty_graph(n = length(vs)) %>%
  set_vertex_attr("name", value = vs) %>%
  Reduce(`+`, ps, init = .) %>%
  simplify() %>%
  set_vertex_attr("val", value = sub(".*_", "", names(V(.))))


lo <- layout_as_tree(g)
lo[, 1] <- ave(lo[, 1], lo[, 2], FUN = \(x) {
  l <- length(x)
  if (l == 1) 0 else seq(-l, l, length.out = l)
})

g %>%
  plot(
    layout = lo,
    vertex.label = V(.)$val,
    vertex.color = as.factor(V(.)$val)
  )
```

and the tree looks like this (the values are specified by colors)

[image]

Comment: thank you so much for your answer! Is it possible to do this in data.tree or diagrammeR?

Comment: I have another bountied question here if you are interested: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77829656/speeding-up-simulations

Comment: @stats_noob sorry that I am not familiar with data.tree or diagrammeR

Comment: I just had an idea ...I will try to reformat the original data... and then use data.tree?

Comment: @stats_noob how do you plan to reformat the original data?

Answer (score 5):

The structure you are trying to create is *not a tree*. In a tree, there is exactly one path between any two nodes[<sup>1</sup>](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tree_(graph_theory)). Although you are starting with a rooted tree, if you merge nodes so that some nodes have two parents, you no longer have a tree, but a *directed acyclic graph* (DAG). This structure cannot be represented by `data.tree`.

Thomas has already given an excellent demonstration of creating the correct DAG with `igraph`. However, if you are producing this graph predominantly for visual output, you could use the `tidygraph` / `ggraph` ecosystem to get an attractive and highly customisable plot.

The following function will output a graph with the correct triangular mesh structure given the starting value, the scores for each win/loss, and the desired depth.

```r
make_tri_mesh <- function(value, scores, depth) {
  height <- rep(seq(depth + 1), seq(depth + 1))
  score <- c(0, lapply(seq(depth), function(x) {
    sort(unique(rowSums(do.call("expand.grid", rep(list(scores), x)))))
  }) |> unlist()) + value
  nodes <- data.frame(node = seq_along(height), height, score)
  from <- rep(unique(nodes$node[nodes$height <= depth]), each = 2)
  to <- unlist(lapply(split(nodes$node, nodes$height)[-1], \(x) {
    if(length(x) == 2) x else head(tail(rep(x, each = 2), -1), -1)}))
  tidygraph::as_tbl_graph(igraph::graph.data.frame(data.frame(from, to))) |> 
    dplyr::mutate(value = nodes$score,
                  yval = max(nodes$height) - nodes$height) |>
    dplyr::group_by(yval) |>
    dplyr::mutate(xval = (seq_along(value) - dplyr::n()/2))
}
```

The output is a `tidygraph` object, which is easy to work with if you are familiar with `tidyverse` data structures.

```r
g <- make_tri_mesh(value = 5, scores = c(-1, 1), depth = 4)

g
#> # A tbl_graph: 15 nodes and 20 edges
#> #
#> # A directed acyclic simple graph with 1 component
#> #
#> # A tibble: 15 x 4
#> # Groups:   yval [5]
#>   name  value  yval  xval
#> * <chr> <dbl> <int> <dbl>
#> 1 1         5     4   0.5
#> 2 2         4     3   0  
#> 3 3         6     3   1  
#> 4 4         3     2  -0.5
#> 5 5         5     2   0.5
#> 6 6         7     2   1.5
#> # i 9 more rows
#> # i Use `print(n = ...)` to see more rows
#> #
#> # A tibble: 20 x 2
#>    from    to
#>   <int> <int>
#> 1     1     2
#> 2     1     3
#> 3     2     4
#> # i 17 more rows
#> # i Use `print(n = ...)` to see more rows
```

And `ggraph` allows bespoke plots with all the familiar ggplot options, plus a few of its own:

```
library(ggraph)
library(ggplot2)

ggraph(g, layout = "manual", x = xval, y = yval) + 
  geom_edge_fan(end_cap = circle(0.9), 
                arrow = arrow(type = "closed", length = unit(3, "mm"))) + 
  geom_node_point(shape = 21, size = 20, aes(fill = value)) + 
  geom_node_text(aes(label = value), size = 6, fontface = 2) +
  theme_void() +
  scale_fill_gradient2(low = "lightblue", mid = "white", high = "pink", 
                       midpoint = 5, guide = "none")
```

[image]

If we wanted to double the depth of the graph, we can simply do:

```r
make_tri_mesh(5, c(-1, 1), 8) |>
  ggraph(layout = "manual", x = xval, y = yval) + 
  geom_edge_fan(end_cap = circle(0.9), 
                arrow = arrow(type = "closed", length = unit(3, "mm"))) + 
  geom_node_point(shape = 21, size = 20, aes(fill = value)) + 
  geom_node_text(aes(label = value), size = 6, fontface = 2) +
  theme_void() +
  scale_fill_gradient2(low = "lightblue", mid = "white", high = "pink", 
                       midpoint = 5, guide = "none")
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks @ThomasIsCoding. My code for producing the actual graph object is a bit clunkier than yours though!

Comment: @ Allan Cameron: thank you so much for this wonderful answer! I love the color coding!

Answer (score 2):

Here is another kind of tree that you might be interested in

```
f <- function(root, depth) {
  cat("\n", sapply(
    Reduce(\(x, y) c(x - 1, max(x) + 1), rep(NA, depth),
      init = root,
      accumulate = TRUE
    ),
    \(x) sprintf("%s\n", paste0(x, collapse = " "))
  ))
}
```

such that, for example

```
> f(5, 7)

 5
 4 6
 3 5 7
 2 4 6 8
 1 3 5 7 9
 0 2 4 6 8 10
 -1 1 3 5 7 9 11
 -2 0 2 4 6 8 10 12
```

Comment: Hi @ThomasIsCoding: I accepted your answer on this question! Thank you so much! I had another bountied question over here - are you familiar with this? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77856515/r-how-to-fit-hidden-markov-models

Comment: @stats_noob unfortunately I am not familiar with HMM