# R: How to Fit Hidden Markov Models

Tags: r

I am working with the R programming language.

Here is a Hidden Markov Model Problem I thought of:

- Suppose there is a red hat and a blue hat.
- Each hat has two balls: ball_1 and ball_2
- We first pick a random hat, and then from the hat we randomly pick a ball
- If we pick the red hat, there is a p1 probability that we pick the red hat again again. If we pick the blue hat, there is a p2 probability we pick the blue hat again.
- If we are in the red hat, and pick ball_1 - there is a p3 probability we pick ball_1 again. If we are in the red hat and pick ball_2 - there is a p4 probability we pick ball_2 again.
- If we are in the blue hat, and pick ball_1 - there is a p5 probability we pick ball_1 again. If we are in the blue hat and pick ball_2 - there is a p6 probability we pick ball_2 again.

We play this "game" 100 times and draw 100 balls. We show the sequence of balls to someone - we only show them which balls were chosen, we do not show them which hats the balls came from.

I wrote a function to represent this problem (I used 0.5 throughout to make it easier):

```
p1 <- 0.5  # Probability of picking the red hat again if we picked the red hat
p2 <- 0.5  # Probability of picking the blue hat again if we picked the blue hat
p3 <- 0.5  # Probability of picking ball_1 again if we are in the red hat and picked ball_1
p4 <- 0.5  # Probability of picking ball_2 again if we are in the red hat and picked ball_2
p5 <- 0.5  # Probability of picking ball_1 again if we are in the blue hat and picked ball_1
p6 <- 0.5  # Probability of picking ball_2 again if we are in the blue hat and picked ball_2

# Initialize 
hat <- sample(c("red", "blue"), 1, prob = c(0.5, 0.5))  # Randomly pick a hat
ball <- sample(c(1, 2), 1, prob = c(0.5, 0.5))  # Randomly pick a ball

# Initialize dataframe 
results <- data.frame(turn = integer(100), hat_color = character(100), ball_number = integer(100))

for (i in 1:100) {

  results[i, "turn"] <- i
  results[i, "hat_color"] <- hat
  results[i, "ball_number"] <- ball
  
  # Update hat and ball
  if (hat == "red") {
    hat <- sample(c("red", "blue"), 1, prob = c(p1, 1 - p1))
    if (ball == 1) {
      ball <- sample(c(1, 2), 1, prob = c(p3, 1 - p3))
    } else {
      ball <- sample(c(1, 2), 1, prob = c(p4, 1 - p4))
    }
  } else {
    hat <- sample(c("red", "blue"), 1, prob = c(p2, 1 - p2))
    if (ball == 1) {
      ball <- sample(c(1, 2), 1, prob = c(p5, 1 - p5))
    } else {
      ball <- sample(c(1, 2), 1, prob = c(p6, 1 - p6))
    }
  }
}
```

The final results look like this:

```
  turn hat_color ball_number
1    1       red           1
2    2       red           2
3    3       red           2
4    4      blue           2
5    5       red           2
6    6       red           1
```

I also plotted the results:

```
library(ggplot2)

results$hat_color <- as.factor(results$hat_color)
results$ball_number <- as.factor(results$ball_number)

ggplot(results, aes(x = turn, y = ball_number, color = hat_color)) +
  geom_point() +
  scale_color_manual(values = c("red" = "red", "blue" = "blue")) +
  labs(x = "Turn Number", y = "Ball Number", color = "Hat Color") +
  theme_minimal()
```

[image]

**My Question:** Suppose we give someone only the vector of `results$ball_number` and we ask them to e**stimate p1,p2,p3,p4, p5, p6**.

I tried to do this with the depmixS4 library (https://www.r-bloggers.com/2018/11/hidden-markov-model-example-in-r-with-the-depmixs4-package/) and try the following code:

```
library(depmixS4)
options(scipen=999)

results$ball_number <- as.numeric(results$ball_number)
n_states <- 2
response <- results$ball_number
mod <- depmix(response ~ 1, nstates = n_states, data = results)
fit.mod <- fit(mod)

getpars(fit.mod)

                    pr1                      pr2                          
1.0000000000000000000000 0.0000000000000000000000 0.4791666666666666851704 
                                                                           
0.5208333333333333703408 0.4705882352941176405281 0.5294117647058823594719 
             (Intercept)                       sd              (Intercept) 
1.0000000000000006661338 0.0000000000000006591584 2.0000000000000017763568 
                      sd 
0.0000000000000013193952
```

But I am not quite sure I have done this correctly.

I then tried to do this with the HMM library (https://reintech.io/blog/understanding-hidden-markov-models-with-r) in R:

```
library(HMM)

observed_sequence <- results$ball_number

transitionMatrix <- matrix(0.5, nrow=2, ncol=2)
emissionMatrix <- matrix(0.5, nrow=2, ncol=2)


hmm <- initHMM(c("red", "blue"), c(1, 2), transitionMatrix, emissionMatrix)

hmm <- baumWelch(hmm, observed_sequence)

print(hmm)
```

It seems like the code ran and the answer looks reasonable:

```
$hmm
$hmm$States
[1] "red"  "blue"

$hmm$Symbols
[1] 1 2

$hmm$startProbs
 red blue 
 0.5  0.5 

$hmm$transProbs
      to
from   red blue
  red  0.5  0.5
  blue 0.5  0.5

$hmm$emissionProbs
      symbols
states    1    2
  red  0.48 0.52
  blue 0.48 0.52


$difference
[1] 0.04000000000000974998 0.00000000000001421085
```

**But I am not sure if I  have done this correctly.
Can someone please show me how to do this? Is there a way to clearly identify p1, p2, p3, p4, p5, p6?**

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

You are probably doing it wrong. I have a few thoughts as for possible ways.
I first redifined your problem and tried using a continuous distribution for simplicity and to be compatible with depmixS4:

```
library(depmixS4)

# Here we convert ball_number to numeric for continuous observations
results$ball_number <- as.numeric(results$ball_number)

# then we define the model
n_states <- 2
response <- results$ball_number

mod <- depmix(response ~ 1, family = gaussian(), nstates = n_states, data = results)
# comment - We are assuming a Gaussian distribution for continuous observations

# Now we are ready to fit the model
fit.mod <- fit(mod)

# Get the estimated parameters
getpars(fit.mod)
```

Comment: I advise you to look for other libraries which specifically designed for discrete HMMs. There are issues with [depmixS4](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/depmixS4/index.html). Let me know how it goes.